# Is it possible to create our own escape sequence in c#?

Tags: c#

As inserting `Environment.NewLine` in string literals reduces readability, I want to create my own escape sequence, for example, `\z` that is equal to `Environment.NewLine`. Is it possible to do this in c#? If yes, how?

## Edit

I have submitted my request for a new escape sequence to the c# language github, please kindly up the request up [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/3241).

Comment: Simple answer: No, you can not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take advantage of [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) (`$`):

```
var nl = Environment.NewLine;
Console.WriteLine($"Hello!{nl}This is Another line of text.{nl}One more.");
```

To be clear, in this code the string `{nl}` will be replaced with the value of the variable `nl`, which is set to `Environment.NewLine`.

See it online [in sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7AHwAEAmARgFgAoaogZgAJSGBhagb2oe6ZJK56cqPEQwBuAQygM8AGwYBeBgFE8YgJZQIeALYw8GAHQA5GAHcAMurwwA3ANFMyATgAUAEgBEACRizZEACE7HIAvgAqABbqAM4MsQwAgngQGJEw0rLWMAwQAGYMGDAIRiGyoQDyNgw60DCGngCU9sI8odShQA===).

*This is not dependent on `Console.WriteLine`. And it is better than `String.Format`... Why? The compiler can optimize string interpolation to `String.Concat` and even bake constants at compile time.*